# Making regex for preg_match greedy to only accept certain values?

Tags: php, regex, date, datetime, preg-match

I have a CSV file that has a entry of strings that represents time/dates as follows :

`20190816T16:10:10`

I have created the following regex to preg_match but want to have the hour/mins and seconds to only allow certain numbers (e.g hours would be 24 hour clock so only accept 00-23, while minutes & seconds would only accept 00-59)

`/\d{8}[A-Z]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}/`

Can anyone suggest how to change this to ensure this regex matches the structure I am trying to achieve?

Comment: Would you like to deal with [leap second](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leap_second)?

Comment: @toto how do you mean exactly?

Comment: Seconds could be `60` like `December 31, 2005 23:59:60 UTC`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify your pattern to match the underlying strings making up those ranges:

```
/\d{8}[A-Z](?:[01][0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]/
```

### Demo

Comment: [0-9] can be just \d?

Comment: @codisfy Yes it could, but I think `[0-9]` reads better in this case given that character classes are used almost everywhere else.

Comment: Makes sense, I was just thinking about brevity.

Answer (score 1):

this regex should match your structure:

```
\d{8}[A-Z]([0-9]|0[0-9]|1[0-9]|2[0-3]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use **ranges** (ex: `[0-9]`), with a *non-capturing group* for the hours (minutes & seconds are easy to match):

```
//            00 to 23       00 to 59
/\d{8}[A-Z](?:[01]\d|2[0-3]):[0-5]\d:[0-5]\d/
```